# Wavelets in Fourier domain

Tags: fourier-analysis, wavelets

Given a wavelet family $\psi_{s, a}$ generated by translations and dilations of a mother wavelet $\psi$
$$
\psi_{s, a}(x)=\frac{1}{s} \psi\left(\frac{x-a}{s}\right)
$$
we can show a wavelet decomposition of signal $f$ as
$$
W_{f}(s, a)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \psi^*_{s, a}(x) d x
$$
where $^*$ denotes complex conjugation. In a paper, $\psi$ is defined in the Fourier domain as
$$\psi_{s, a}(x)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{\psi}(s \omega) e^{-j \omega a} e^{j \omega x} d \omega$$
I was wondering if someone can help me to see where this comes from. Thanks!

---

**My try:** An inverse Fourier transform is written as
$$\psi_{s, a}(x)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \widehat{\psi_{s, a}}(\omega) e^{i \omega x} d \omega$$
On the other hand 
\begin{align}
\widehat{\psi_{s, a}}(\omega) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi_{s, a}(x) e^{-i \omega x} d x\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{s} \psi\left(\frac{x-a}{s}\right) e^{-i \omega x} d x\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\widehat{\psi}$ represents the Fourier transform of $\psi$ then

$$
\psi(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \widehat{\psi}(\omega) e^{j\omega x}{\rm d}\omega \tag{1}
$$

Now consider the expression

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \widehat{\psi}(s\omega) e^{-j\omega a}e^{j\omega x}{\rm d}\omega &=& 
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \widehat{\psi}(s\omega) e^{j\omega(x-a)}{\rm d}\omega \\
&=& \frac{1}{2\pi s}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \widehat{\psi}(\color{blue}{s\omega}) e^{j(\color{blue}{s\omega})(x-a)/s}{\rm d}(\color{blue}{s\omega}) \\
&\stackrel{\nu = \color{blue}{s\omega}}{=}& \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \widehat{\psi}(\nu) e^{j\nu(x - a)/s}{\rm d}\nu \\
&\stackrel{y = (x-a)/s}{=}& \frac{1}{s}\left\{\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \widehat{\psi}(\nu) e^{j\nu y}{\rm d}\nu\right\} \\
&\stackrel{(1)}{=}& \frac{1}{s}\psi(y) = \frac{1}{2}\psi\left(\frac{x - a}{s}\right) \\
&=& \psi_{s,a}(x) \tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thank you for the detailed derivation!